# Form OnPaint not clearing previous paints

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to override the paint event of a Windows Form, however all painting I do to the Form stays, even after I've `Invalidate()` and `Update()` the Form.

I am using a Timer to `Invalidate()` and `Update()` the Form, which causes the `OnPaint()` to be called

Here is the code:

```
// In the constructor the timer is created and enabled
private void UpdaterElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    WIDGET.Invalidate();
    WIDGET.Update();
}
private void WIDGET_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.High;
    e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    String text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, new Font("Arial", 32), Brushes.Black, new Point(0, 0));
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the control `WIDGET`?

Comment: `e.Graphics.Clear(yourBackgroundColor);`

Comment: It is not the job of the Paint event to clear anything.  OnPaintBackground() does that, it applies the BackColor.  Very unclear why it doesn't get the job done, your snippet is not useful.

Comment: This is MCVE closure as per what @HansPassant said. Or, another angle, use the proper `event`

Answer (score 1):

It's not supposed to clear the form (though getting paint events triggered by covering your window should do the job anyway). Simply clear it yourself if you need to:

```
e.Graphics.Clear(/* insert your color here */);
```

Comment: The issue with this is that the background color I would like to use is Color.Transparent.  Which draws black instead.

Comment: @KFCChicken Maybe your question should have mentioned that.  There is an edit link under your post.

Comment: @KFCChicken, then you have two cases. You either actually mean the window background system color (in which case look at the `SystemColors` class) or you want to draw it over a background, in which case you'd use `Graphics.DrawImage` to "clear" it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear graphics with some color which should be considered as transparent and then simply setup transparency key.

```
e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Purple);
this.TransparencyKey = Color.Purple;
```

[image: result]

Comment: The issue with this is that if the color of the text was purple then it would disappear as well, no?

Comment: @KFCChicken When the TransparencyKey property is assigned a Color, the areas of the form that have the same BackColor will be displayed transparently. [see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @lale This is the issue though. Whatever color was set the TransparencyKey can then not be used for drawing purposes.